# Access Object property in APEX

Tags: json, object, deserialize

Given the next code:

```
    Object deserializeResponse = JSON.deserializeUntyped(response);
    System.debug('DESERIALIZERESPONSE' + deserializeResponse);
    //DESERIALIZERESPONSE: {proposalIds=null, response=true}
    System.assert(deserializeResponse.response ==true);
```

I need to access to response property of the deserializeResponse Object. How can I do it? Because, right now, I have the next compilation error: **Variable does not exist: response**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `deserializeUntyped`, that means, `deserializeResponse` as Object does not know about its structure during compilation. Try this approach:

```
Map<String, Object> deserializeResponse = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response);
System.assert((Boolean) deserializeResponse.get('response'));
```

Comment: Simple but effective. Thank you so much!

Comment: The Object knows about its structure at runtime, but the compiler does not know at compile-time, hence the need to cast.

Answer (score 3):

The `Object` type is not really something we can use directly in Apex. I don't believe it has any fields/properties, and only has a few known (but undocumented) methods.

The generally preferred approach to deserializing JSON in Apex is to create a series of classes that match the structure of the JSON you're trying to deserialize.

In this case, that would look something like this:

```
public class MyJsonData{
    public List<Id> proposalIds;
    public Boolean response;
}

// Even though we're telling JSON.deserialize() to use MyJsonData as a template
//   of sorts, it always returns an Object, so we need to do a little type-casting
MyJsonData data = (MyJsonData)JSON.deserialize(response, MyJsonData.class);

// When working with booleans, there is no need to test for equality to true
//   (or false, either).
System.assert(data.response);
```

`JSON.deserializeUntyped()` is generally used when your JSON data contains something problematic for Salesforce like a reserved word (break, continue, switch) or things like `__c`.

deserializeUntyped() also returns an Object, but it actually is either a `Map<String, Object>` or a `List<Object>`, depending on whether the topmost element in the JSON is a (JSON) object or a list. In your case, you'd get a `Map<String, Object>`.

Using a `Map<String, Object>` can involve a lot of extra type-casting (which is why at least I prefer defining classes for the deserialization), but in your case would be fairly simple.

```
Map<String, Object> data = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(response);

Boolean jsonResponse = (Boolean)data.get('response');

System.assert(jsonResponse);
```

Comment: So instructive, I've learned a little bit more about Object, Serialize, JSON, and so on... Thank you!

Comment: As you say, `Object` has no properties, and two methods, `equals` and `hashCode`. `JSON.deserializeUntyped` can also return a String, Boolean, Decimal, or null value as well. Overall, nice work, though.